# postfix setup as a cloud mail gateway with exchange 2013 internally

Tags: email, postfix

we have a mail server on the cloud running postfix on ubuntu 12.0, and recently we wanted to setup exchange for the sake of calendar sharing and address book also to integrate with sharepoint and lync.

I can send from exchange clients to the outside world through our cloud server smarthost. I can send and receive from exchange clients internally. but when sending from gmail to the cloud server, I receive it on the cloud server but I never receive it on the internal exchange server.

what I want to do is, I want emails to be forwarded to my internal exchange server. at the same time I want to keep a copy of the email in the cloud server. I've been told that smtp relay will not leave a copy on the server!!! if its what I need can you detail what I need to update in my main.cf file in /etc/postfix.

on my firewall I have opened all the ports for connections from the cloud server, and the natted the connections to my internal exchange server. but still I can not receive emails.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Postfix documentation regarding mail forwarding domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding). This may fix your issue with outside email systems getting mail to your Exchange system.

The same document covers [virtual domains with mailbox stores](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox).

This may give you some leads on how to configure Postfix to accomplish what you're trying to achieve. I do believe however that since Postfix is primarily an MTA, getting it configured to act as a replica of your Exchange system is going to be challenging.

Comment: thanks douqqro for helping out. but i don't think mail forwarding domain is what I want postfix to do. cause it clearly says that "the main purpose of these domains is to forward mail elsewhere." although I want mail to be fwd to my local exchange, I also want to leave a copy on the postfix server.

Comment: Your only option then would be to configure something like Dovecot to act as a local service on the server along with also forwarding to Exchange. The problem there is maintaining the list of users and mailboxes between systems.

Comment: I was reading on postfix configuration with exchange. it says that if you leave my_destination= empty inside the main.cf file your post fix will not be considered as a final destination. further is says that all domains needs to be under relay_domains= . my question is if I put the exchange server as well as my postfix server under relay_domains will it send two copies, one to exchange and one locally.

Comment: You would still need some destination for the relays to deliver to.